# How do you train a clustering model?

Tags: clustering, algorithms, unsupervised-learning

This should've been a pretty simple question, but I still have a few questions so I decided to bring the discussion here.

The thing is, I have a group of products, and the historical dataset looks like this:

```
Product_name      selling_rate      revenue_per_unit        buyers_per_bid
ABCD              20%               $100                    5 
EFGH              10%               $200                    2
IJKL              30%               $500                    1
PPPP              15%               $600                    10
```

I wanted to group them. I thought about using something like a K-means algorithm.

My question is, how do I train this model?

Let's say I find out I can group them into two groups, with ABCD and EFGH being in group 1 and IJKL and PPPP in group 2. Is there a way to test if these clusters are a good choice?

I based on the way this tutorial grouped the products using k-means: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/customer-segmentation-tutorial-data-science-in-the-industry-a6b486f0b0b0.

Any ideas are super welcome and if there's anything missing here just mentioned. There are too many private information, so I needed to adapt the problem.